# How to get check multiple events in google analytics in one go?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to check the count of multiple events day wise in google analytics. For example, currently, I have to manually filter each of the events.

Is there any UI in GA where I can put details of multiple events and get their respective day-wise count? The advanced filter either has regex OR containing but what if my events have no common pattern. I don't see option to add OR condition i.e. action 1st OR action 2nd ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and save a custom report. You can use regex in the filter with a pipe character | as a separator between each action (or category, or label, depending on what field you are using within the filter). A | is "or" when using regex.